# How do you get the count sum of a field in a related - related table?

Tags: mysql, join, count, sum

I have three tables:

**Zones Table:**

```
+--------------------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field                    | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                       | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| location_id              | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| impressions_count        | bigint(20) unsigned | YES  |     | 0       |                |
| created                  | datetime            | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| modified                 | datetime            | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+--------------------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

**Locations Table:**

```
+----------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field          | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id             | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| retailer_id    | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| zones_count    | int(10) unsigned    | YES  |     | 0       |                |
| contacts_count | int(10) unsigned    | YES  |     | 0       |                |
| created        | datetime            | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| modified       | datetime            | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+----------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

**Retailers Table:**

```
+---------------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field               | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                  | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| account_rep_id      | bigint(20) unsigned | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| leadsource_id       | bigint(20) unsigned | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| industry_id         | bigint(20)          | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| name                | varchar(100)        | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| locations_count     | int(10) unsigned    | YES  |     | 0       |                |
| created             | datetime            | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| modified            | datetime            | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+---------------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

**What I want to to do:**

I am selecting all records from the `Retailers` table. The `Retailers` table has many records in `Locations`, which in turn has many records in `Zones`.

The `Zones` table has a field called `impressions_count`. What I want to do, is select all records from the `Retailers` table, while joining to the `Locations` table and the `Zones` table.

Essentially, I *think* I need to return a SUM(Zones.impressions_count) for each matching record in `Locations` and then a sum of that for each record in `Retailers`. I have been banging my head against the wall for a while - and appreciate any guidance!

Ultimately: my result set should look like this:

```
**from retailers**
id,
account_rep_id,
lead_source_id,
industry_id,
impressions_count,   // <- sum of related records in `Zones`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you join to location you likely want to use an inline view to aggregate the data by location before the join... So...

This is done so the one to many relationship between the tables doesn't artificially increase the sum of impression_count by Location_ID

```
Select * 
FROM retailers R
INNER JOIN Locations L
  on R.ID = L.retailer_id
INNER JOIN 
(Select sum(impressions_count) as cnt, Location_ID from Zones group by Location_ID) as Z
  on Z.Location_ID = L.ID
```

Now.. if you're not displaying location in your output and you want a sum by retailer.. then we need to sum again.. this time summing the values by retailer for each location...

```
Select R.id
      ,R.account_rep_id
      ,R.lead_source_id
      ,R.industry_id
      ,coalesce(sum(cnt),0) as impressions_count
FROM retailers R
LEFT JOIN Locations L
  on R.ID = L.retailer_id
LEFT JOIN 
(Select coalesce(sum(impressions_count),0) as cnt, Location_ID from Zones group by Location_ID) as Z
  on Z.Location_ID = L.ID
GROUP BY R.id
        ,R.account_rep_id
        ,R.lead_source_id
        ,R.industry_id
```

Comment: That is very close! only problem is, it doesn't return Retailers with zero impressions. This may be fixed with a different join however.

Comment: easy enough change the inner to left. and we may need to coalesce... (updated)

Comment: Works like a champ. Cheers!